# Blackberry10 NetworkAccessManager: The bound address already in use

Tags: qt, http, networking, blackberry-10

I'm having issues with the NetworkAccessManager.get method. When i make two http-connections, the second connection fails with the error "99: The bound addres is already in use".

I start the second connection in the finish-slot of the first connection. Maybe multiple async http-connections are not supported on BB-10?

Doest anyone got the same error?

Answer (score 0):

In essence you should only be using a single instance of the NetworkAccessManager but passing multiple requests through it.  The documentation (http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) specifies the following:

> One QNetworkAccessManager should be enough for the whole Qt
> application.
>
> ...
>
> QNetworkAccessManager has an asynchronous API. When the replyFinished slot above is called, the parameter it takes is the QNetworkReply object containing the downloaded data as well as meta-data (headers, etc.).
>
> ...
>
> Note: QNetworkAccessManager queues the requests it receives. The number of requests executed in parallel is dependent on the protocol. Currently, for the HTTP protocol on desktop platforms, 6 requests are executed in parallel for one host/port combination.

So basically what you should be doing is sending multiple requests through the same NetworkAccessManager and then handling the response based on the meta-data.  The NetworkAccessManager will handle the async processing for you.

Comment: could you add some code to your question showing how you call the networkaccessmanager?